# Is assigning a number too big to be represented in a bit field undefined behaviour

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, undefined-behavior, bit-fields

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

enum nums {
    ONE,
    TWO,
    TWENTY = 20
};

struct field {

    uint32_t something : 4;
    uint32_t rest : 28;
};

int main(void) {

    struct field f;
    f.something = TWENTY;
    return 0;
}
```

On a powerpc 8241 running RTEMS 4.9.1, compiled with minGW GCC 3.4.5 (I know its old) this code will cause a segfault. The reason i have determined is that we are setting a number to big to be represented by a bit field to the bitfield in question. Since we have 4 bits it should only be able to represent 0 -> 15, and indeed when we set it with these numbers it works fine. Anything above and it crashes. I am unable to reproduce this behavior [here](http://ideone.com/fzPpfT), so my question is:

**Is this *undefined behavior*? If so, is there a reference in a c standard that covers it?**

Or is it more likely just a bug because of our *very* old compiler?

Comment: It would be interesting to compile with the `-S` flag to see the generated assembly language.

Comment: @lurker that can probably be arranged ...

Comment: This question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151305/gcc-warning-large-integer-implicitly-truncated-to-unsigned-type#2151321. If you add `-Werror` flag to GCC then should expectet output be: `error: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Werror=overflow] f.something = TWENTY;`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I compiled it with `gcc` version 4.7.2 without any particular flags and it threw a warning, `large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]`. The assembly read the lowest byte of the structure into `%eax`, zeroed out the low 4 bits, or'ed in the value `4` (which is `20` truncated to 4 bits) and wrote the byte back out to the struct.

Comment: @lurker I have -wall on and i get nothing. Must be the old compiler ... Still, shouldn't cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: I agree totally it should not cause a segmentation fault. Warning or no, it should just truncate to the allocated number of bits. As I mentioned, it would be quite interesting to see what the code generation looks like, just out of curiosity. The newer compiler generates code that constrains the bits so completely circumvents the possibility of that kind of fault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a bug, at least in C99 this is well defined behavior, from the draft c99 standard section 6.2.6 Representations of types:

> Values stored in unsigned bit-fields and objects of type unsigned char
>   shall be represented using a pure binary notation.40

and later on in section 6.2.5 Types:

> A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because
>   a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer
>   type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest
>   value that can be represented by the resulting type.